# BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 12.422 secs 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to run `react-native run-android` it gives an error, something like this.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 12.422 secs
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Starting the app (c:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
```

and in the emulator it says

```
the development server returned response error code:500
```

with a red screen. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: how can i fix this

Comment: i did add this to system variable path

Comment: are you able to run adb from the terminal ?

Comment: thank problem is actully i needed to restart after setting up system variables